# What's the most triangles you can make with 4, 5 or 6 straight lines?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, no-computers, optimization

All the triangles can stick together. The triangles counted is the independent triangles, triangles made up of two shapes, a triangle made up from 3 shapes, or the outline of the shape consisting of 4, 5 or 6 lines.

Comment: In Euclidean geometry?

Answer (score 8):

I seem to recall that the solution to this problem for $n$ lines is

> $n \choose 3$, so for 4 lines it's 4, for 5 lines it's 10 and for 6 lines it's 20.

The idea is that

> each combination of 3 lines generates exactly one triangle. They intersect in at most 3 points, which form the triangle. Actually, as long as you don't choose parallel lines, they *will* intersect in exactly 3 points. There are $n \choose 3$ of these combinations.

For example, here is the solution for 6 lines:

> [image]
>  The triangles are formed by:
>  ABC, ADE, AGI, AHJ
>  FGH, FIJ, FLN, FMO
>  KLM, KNO, KBD, KCE
>  BIO, BJM, CGO, CHM
>  DIN, DJL, EGN, EHL

Comment: Very nice! I suppose you could just ignore 1 or 2 lines in the above diagram to get the optimal solution for 5 and 4 lines.